# Starting more than one (background worker) process in a production environment on CloudFoundry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry, foreman, procfile, god

I have a RoR application and deploy it to CloudFoundry. Together with the application itself I want to start a Resque scheduler and a couple of workers.

I tried various szenarios:

- Procfile: Multiple processes supported from v3, which is experimental and does not support manifest files yet;
- Foreman: Actually works, but is not recommended for production usage due to lack of proper process management
- Upstart: Not possible as it would need root privileges
- Directly via command (-c): It is possible to execute multiple daemon processes using & between them. However, in this case terminated processes are not restarted (no health check available).

So I am ending up to specify a separate app for each process in my manifest file. I just can't believe that this is the best practice here?! Not only from a resources perspective, but also from a workflow perspective (think of the duration for a deployment for a couple of apps).

Bottom line, my question here is: What is the best approach to start more than one (worker) process in a production environment on CloudFoundry? I am thinking of -c option plus Monit or God, but I am afraid this would require root privileges again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this option:

> Procfile: Multiple processes supported from v3, which is experimental and does not support manifest files yet;

I know it says "experimental", but that's only to say that there's the technical possibility that API's to Cloud Controller could change. It does *not* mean that there's anything inherently unstable about using this option. Your processes run in exactly the same way they do when deploying multiple apps (your 4th option), it's just a different way of organizing resources them in Cloud Controller.

I believe that manifest file support will come, hopefully soon. There's a big effort going on as I write this to finish the v3 API & deprecate the v2 API. You might be a little ahead of the curve here, but not much. You'll also be well positioned for the future if you go this route.

Hope that helps!